# What is wrong with this homotopy? [Basic question]

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, alternative-proof

For a loop $a$ around $x$ and $\overline{a}$ its opposite, I want to construct an homotopy between $a \cdot \overline a$ and $c_x$. The usual solution is the one that can be found for example [here](https://topospaces.subwiki.org/wiki/Homotopy_between_constant_loop_and_composite_of_loop_with_inverse).

However I was wondering if there is anything wrong with another one, namely 
$H(x,t)= 
\left\{\begin{array}{lr}
        a(2tx) &  0\leq x\leq 1/2\\
        a(2t-2tx) &  1/2\leq x\leq 1\
        \end{array} \right |?$

If no, then is there any benefit to using the usual one?

Comment: Yours is a fine homotopy. I don't see an advantage to the other one, but it's possible that it is more convenient for some things I don't currently think of.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Daniel Fischer noted, the given homotopy is also viable.